# Dell Precision M4400 Overheating and FPS drops

Tags: windows-7, gpu, cooling, overheating, dell-precision

The dell laptop that I have keeps overheating during games and the fps drops about 20 minutes after the game starts. I have disabled Speed Step, lowered the processing power in Windows Power Options to the minimum but I still have this problem. The GPU heats up to around 65 C and the cores around 55-60.

Are there a way to stop the fps drops and/or overheating? Thanks.

Comment: Power the device down, disconnect the battery, and ensure it's unplugged from any electrical power. Get a can of compressed air and blow it through every hole you can find in the enclosure including any fan areas. This will help break and loosen up any dust that's accumulated and help the air flow get back to normal potentially. This may be an easy solution worth a try in case it's simply dust restricting air flow in this laptop and that contributing to the heat not dissipating elsewhere away from applicable circuitry within the device.